# Floating elements within a horizontal scrolling container

Tags: html, css, css-float

How can I stop these elements from wrapping with the browser window without setting a fixed width for the container?

```
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<style>

#container {
  height: 300px;
}

#container > div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

</style>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrapping with the browser window"?

Comment: I mean, I want them to display in a horizontal line, even if they get go off the edge of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to scroll horizontally, you'll need to specify `overflow-x: auto`. I'll post an example ASAP.

Comment: In my book, ASAP isn't over 2 years.